# Blender 2.83 model invisible glitch

Tags: objects, 3d-view, interface

https://gyazo.com/b3d840f42a8f57c23fb80645ba9f1e48

Something has happened today while I was modelling.

Magically my model became invisible and when I go to the material preview or render view, the model turns black and appears to shrink and contort itself.

This hasn't really ever happened, I thought it'll just go away if I restart blender but that didn't happen, I also created another blender file to see if its only something I did in the previous blend file but the same thing happened, invisible object. I looked if anyone has had this problem  as well but I couldn't find anything. What's interesting is that despite the actual model and its parts being invisible,the lamp, camera and reference images were completely visible and functional.

I tried restarting blender, reinstalling blender, restarting my computer, nothings worked, I checked if I maybe enabled something in blender that made  this happen, but again, I didn't find anything.

I really need help with this, cause I can't really make a model if I can't see it.

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but one more thing you can try - open 2 instances of blender - one with your troublesome file and another empty one (default cube, lamp, and camera deleted). Select all and copy (Ctrl+C) from the file that's acting up, and then paste (Ctrl+V) into the empty project. This will at least tell you if you just accidentally messed up some viewport/project setting in your original file, or if there's something more going on with the models themselves.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site 
to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. 
See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact problem, so I went into *Viewport Shading* and was able to see the model.

Then I opened another instance of Blender and copy/pasted there and was able to see it and work on it.